# WebAPI 2 - Custom content types and negotiation

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Really simple question but I can't find a simple example in the docs, or whether it'll just work.

I want to version one of my API resources. I want to add `application/vnd.myEntityV2+json` and `...+xml` as custom content types, then check the Accept header in my controller and call the appropriate code. Simple idea.

Will the built-in WebAPI content negotiation see the `+json|+xml` on the end and pick the right formatter?

Or do I need to configure two mappings, or something else completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've done:

```
JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().Single();
jsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
    new RequestHeaderMapping(HttpRequestHeaders.Accept, "+json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, true, new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeTypes.ApplicationJson)));
```

Note `HttpRequestHeaders` and `MimeTypes` are my own types.

That should catch any content-type containing `+json`.